# How to I reshpae the pandas dataframe containing duplicate values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

I have the folloing data frame containing weather paramters for different timestamps for 24 hour period:

```
   **category     fcstValue             Timestamp**
0   TMP         13               2022-10-05 06:00:00
3   VEC         62               2022-10-05 06:00:00
4   WSD         1.7              2022-10-05 06:00:00
5   SKY         4                2022-10-05 06:00:00
6   PTY         0                2022-10-05 06:00:00
10  REH         85               2022-10-05 06:00:00
12  TMP         14               2022-10-05 07:00:00
15  VEC         80               2022-10-05 07:00:00
16  WSD         1.7              2022-10-05 07:00:00
17  SKY         4                2022-10-05 07:00:00
```

I want to reshape it into following format:

```
Timestamp            TMP VEC WSD SKY PTY REH SNO
2022-10-05 00:00:00                         
2022-10-05 00:01:00                         
2022-10-05 00:02:00                         
2022-10-05 00:03:00                         
2022-10-05 00:04:00                         
2022-10-05 00:05:00                         
2022-10-05 00:06:00  13  62  1.7 4   0   85  -
```

I have tried to use the pandas.pivot option however it results in an error because of duplicate enteries in columns. I also treid the pandas.groupby option and though it did stacked the data but then again I am stuck at how to change the weather paramters into column headers to get required DataFrame.

```
df1=df1.groupby(by=['Timestamp'])

category    fcstValue   Timestamp
0   TMP       13    2022-10-05 06:00:00
3   VEC       62    2022-10-05 06:00:00
4   WSD      1.7    2022-10-05 06:00:00
5   SKY        4    2022-10-05 06:00:00
6   PTY        0    2022-10-05 06:00:00
... ... ... ...
277 TMP      12     2022-10-05 05:00:00
280 VEC      35     2022-10-05 05:00:00
281 WSD     2.1     2022-10-05 05:00:00
282 SKY       4     2022-10-05 05:00:00
283 PTY       0     2022-10-05 05:00:00
```

Furthermore, I also tried the solution mentioned in another similar post(using pivot tables) but in that case I recieve an empty datafrmae as output:

Is there any simpler way to achieve the required shape of dataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that OP's dataframe is `df` and looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['TMP', 'VEC', 'WSD', 'SKY', 'PTY', 'REH', 'TMP', 'VEC', 'WSD', 'SKY'], 'fcstValue': [13, 62, 1.7, 4, 0, 85, 14, 80, 1.7, 4], 'Timestamp': ['2022-10-05 06:00:00', '2022-10-05 06:00:00', '2022-10-05 06:00:00', '2022-10-05 06:00:00', '2022-10-05 06:00:00', '2022-10-05 06:00:00', '2022-10-05 07:00:00', '2022-10-05 07:00:00', '2022-10-05 07:00:00', '2022-10-05 07:00:00']})

[Out]:
  category  fcstValue            Timestamp
0      TMP       13.0  2022-10-05 06:00:00
1      VEC       62.0  2022-10-05 06:00:00
2      WSD        1.7  2022-10-05 06:00:00
3      SKY        4.0  2022-10-05 06:00:00
4      PTY        0.0  2022-10-05 06:00:00
5      REH       85.0  2022-10-05 06:00:00
6      TMP       14.0  2022-10-05 07:00:00
7      VEC       80.0  2022-10-05 07:00:00
8      WSD        1.7  2022-10-05 07:00:00
9      SKY        4.0  2022-10-05 07:00:00
```

In order to get the dataframe in the desired format, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) as follows

```
df = df.pivot(index='Timestamp', columns='category', values='fcstValue')


[Out]:

category             PTY   REH  SKY   TMP   VEC  WSD
Timestamp                                           
2022-10-05 06:00:00  0.0  85.0  4.0  13.0  62.0  1.7
2022-10-05 07:00:00  NaN   NaN  4.0  14.0  80.0  1.7
```

---

**Note:**

- As one can only comment with the data that one has access to, this approach using the dataframe that OP shares in the question does the work.